# Два одинаковых имени в одном пространстве имён

Tags: c++, qt

Проблема: пишу код в qt. Хочу подключиться к серверу через системный вызов connect. Компилятор ругается, говорит что не те аргументы для функции connect из qt, которая работает с сигналами и слотами. Получается он просто не видит connect  из posix что ли. Как решить такую проблему?

Comment: попробуйте в начале имени функции написать дважды двоеточие. То есть, где то так `::connect(...)`

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и полный текст ошибки. В qt  нет функции `connect`, но есть `QObject::connect`. Проверьте, не вызываете ли вы его.

Comment: Спасибо большое)) не додумался. Кстати, почему так происходит? Я вызывал эту функцию в области видимости класса Widget и компилятор имел ввиду именно её. Разве не должно быть типичной перегрузки? Получается что просто функция connect из qt вытеснила connect posix

Comment: Да, вызывался QObject::connect

Comment: Это происходит так как в C++ неконсистентные правила для разруливания конфликтов имен. В этом случае метод класса считается приоритетным.

Comment: вполне себе нормальные правила. Просто, как в любом случае их просто нужно знать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае конфликта имен имеет смысл указывать полное имя. Так как нужная функция находится в глобальном списке имен (global namespace), то для этого пишем так  `::connect(..)`.

Такая же история и с функцией `bind`. Она есть в библиотеке сокетов, так и `std::bind`, который иногда в купе с `using namespace std;` может приводить к феерическим результатам.

Answer (score 0):

Метод `connect()` является статическим методом в классе QObject.
Есть функция connect(), которая входит в библиотеку для работы с сокетами,
поэтому вам не выводится сообщение, что нет такой функции, а что аргументы 
не соответствующие